# ampersand (&) sign in sitemap generating error

Tags: google, sitemap, xml

I have ampersand  sign in urls and Google is not able to parse my sitemap.xml due to this.

I can't remove the sign but i have to submit my xml to google.

Is there any solution for this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In XML the ampersand has to be escaped, so change it to: `&amp;`

Comment: More details can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091945/where-can-i-get-a-list-of-the-xml-document-escape-characters